# Not sure whether to replace my ram or not

Tags: memory, bsod

I've seem to have a ram problem since a while, according to forum posts etc, so i decided to run the windows memory diagnostic tool, after i logged in again, it said "your computer has a memory problem", what exactly does this mean?

**Is my ram faulty ?**

**Could it be something else than my ram ?**

**If it is my ram, do I need to replace it, or do i need to do some more tests?**

I really hope you guys could help me out on this one.

Comment: Run a diagnostic like Memtest86+ across it - if you get a single error, test your sticks individually and replace any bad ones.

Comment: that does take forever right ? and what if 1 of the 2 is faulty, replace both or just the one stick, because i've heard that 2 different sticks sometimes also cause problems

Comment: Doesn't take too long to do a single pass, which is usually enough if you have particularly faulty RAM. 2 different sticks isn't usually a problem, although if one has failed they're usually manufactured in pairs so it's often a good idea to replace the pair.

Comment: alright ill do a memtest then, that works the same as like when you want to  boot a windows installation from an usb right ?

Comment: You can install it to a bootable USB stick, sure.

Comment: Ill be on it then, ill report here again with the results if thats alright :)

Answer (score 2):

Do as [Jonno](https://superuser.com/users/536125/jonno) says, and test again with [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).
This will give you pretty clear results if your RAM is faulty.

However if you have multiple sticks of RAM Memtest86+ will not, from my experience, tell you which one is faulty.

So after running the test on all your ram, if you get an error, test each stick seperately and replace the ones giving you errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i think if it turns out one of the 2 is faulty. ill probably replace them both

Comment: @DennisHeitinga There is absolutely no need to replace both if only one is faulty, unless you want to use the opportunity to up the capacity, or replace 2 sticks with a single stick which you want to place in the known good socket.